# No module named CFFI from FFI

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am very new to Python. I installed `scrapy` and it installed properly but when I want to run it using scrapy command it says

```
"No module named CFFI from FFI"
```

any help please?

Comment: okay just installing CFFI solves the problem

Comment: Fixed typos, added code formatting.

Answer (score 6):

```
pip install cffi
```

solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Run the python IDLE shell and type in import cffi. If there's no issue in importing, then CFFI is actually installed and the issue is something else.

The best way to install python modules is pip install cffi. If you already have it installed, upgrade using the pip command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install required lib:

```
pip install libtcod-cffi==0.2.8
```